# Manually trigger @input using redactor wysiwyg html editor

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, redactor

I had implemented an Auto complete people/apps list like Facebook or Google using @ input with jQuery in my rails app within certain textboxes. Everything is working fine until lately I needed to implement a WYSIWYG html editor on the same textboxes.

The best editor I found was [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) and implemented it and it works fine too. The problem now is my `@ autocomplete` gets lost and is not triggered with redactor in place.

Is there a way I can keep the redactor and still have my `@ automplete` functionality still working inside redactor?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Never found a working solution :-(